# Rails: share information within a Request scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails

What's the mechanism in Rails to share information within the current request scope?

Those familiar with Asp.Net would know there is a HttpContext that is available to all the entities that are invoked during a request.

Anything similar in Rails?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With `around_filter` and `Thread.current[]` you can easily create a request context/scope. See the following example.

First add in your `application_controller.rb`:

```
  around_filter :request_context

  def request_context
    begin
      RequestContext.begin_request
      yield
    ensure
      RequestContext.end_request
    end
  end
```

now add the following class to `lib/request_context.rb`

```
class RequestContext
  def self.instance
    i = Thread.current[:request_context]
    unless i
      raise "No instance present. In script/rakefiles: use RequestContext.with_scope {}, " +
            "in controller: ensure `around_filter :request_scope` is configured"
    end
    return i
  end

  # Allows the use of this scope from rake/scripts
  # ContextScope.with_scope do |scope|
  #   # do something
  #   ...
  # end
  def self.with_scope
    begin
      begin_request
      yield(instance)
    ensure
      end_request
    end
  end

  def self.begin_request
    raise "request_context already set" if Thread.current[:request_context]
    Thread.current[:request_context] = RequestContext.new
  end

  def self.end_request
    raise "request_context already nil" unless Thread.current[:request_context]
    Thread.current[:request_context] = nil
  end

  # user part, add constructors/getters/setters here

  def initialize
    # you can setup stuff here, be aware that this
    # is being called in _every_ request.
  end
end
```

This is pretty straightforward. You can store data in the RequestContext.instance object, the object will get recreated after every request.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't one built in to the best of my knowledge. The need for a request-scoped hash is a bad smell in my books. Every request has just one associated action, and from there you should be using your model objects to do the majority of the work.

Think about the Rails MVC "request" pipeline:

1. The browser makes a request to a URI
2. Rails looks up the controller and action based on the routing information
3. Rails creates a *single* instance of that controller and calls the action as a method (with any params[] as a parameter)

That single controller instance that gets created in response to a request is scoped to your *current* request only (i.e.; exactly what you're looking for). If you need to share request data, put it on your controller or better yet, put it in your action, or even better... In your models.

Why do you need this?

Comment: I have a set of session scoped data(relating to the user obviously) which i would like the model have access to. I neither own the controllers or model, either case I need to monkey patch controllers/model. Thought just patching model would be the easiest because it is only one place. if I were to change controllers there are quite a few of them that need to change. Now I know model doesnt have direct access to session data(dont like the ugly work arounds to enable that either). Was wondering if there is a request hash, to which I could push the session info and let model read from there!

Comment: The "proper" way to do this would be to just pass the user model in to any other model that needs it, either as a parameter or through associations. If you're trying to avoid changing controllers and models and are convinced that you have to do this, I'd say there's nothing inherently worse in letting models access the session data than letting them access request data. Especially if the data's already in the session.

Comment: "... I'd say there's nothing inherently worse in letting models access the session data than letting them access request data". Thats a fair point i would agree to! Lemme rework my solution so it fits in to the "proper" way. Thanks for your comments

Comment: @JeffPerrin This is not an answer. I think you should add a comment under the question. You may not like sharing request data with model code but I can think about a dozen of real World use cases for this technique.

Comment: @WilsonFreitas I think I did answer the question: "There isn't one built in to the best of my knowledge". As far as I know, there's nothing analogous to the global HttpContext in Rails. I suppose you could grab data from the request within the controller and then stick it it Thread.current, but there's still no HttpContext.Current.Request type object that's accessible to models.

Comment: @JeffPerrin I think you are right. Is Thread.current safe for this purpose? I use to do the same thing in Java (using ThreadLocal) and it works fine on Servlet containers. I need to share a piece of data (current user id) with rails models and maybe Thread.current is the way to go.

Comment: I've used Thread.current on several apps and haven't had any problems. Create a before_filter in application controller, grab the info that you need and stuff it in Thread.current. It can then be accessed anywhere. Again, I wouldn't recommend it for most uses, but sometimes there's not a better way.