# How to discard class attributes after request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Here's the problem:

```
class Man
    def self.the_man
        @the_man ||= find_by(id: 1)
    end
end
```

`the_man` is requested in both controller and view, and I'm accessing `Man.the_man` directly in the view instead of instantiating it in the controller. It retains the same record across requests.

I tried to replace it with:

```
Thread.current[:the_man] ||= find_by(id: 1)
```

but the result is the same.

How can I make `Man` trigger `find_by` only once per request?

Comment: Have you tried to use `@@the_man` instead_of `@the_man` ?

Comment: Why are you assigning it to `@the_man` if you don't want it to persist between requests?

Comment: @Jordan I don't want to sound rude but there is two possible answers.
First: I didn't know. Second: Is an example to what I want to archive. Doesn't matter.
That fact that is persisting between request is the problem, it's obvious, that's why I've made the question.
Thanks anyway.

Comment: What I meant is that you could solve the persistence problem by not putting that value in a variable (`def self.the_man; find_by(id: 1) end`). Is there a reason you don't want to do that? It's difficult to answer your question without that information.

Comment: @Jordan the problem is that I use Man.the_man a lot, and every time I do so, Rails queries the database.

Comment: Rails has [some pretty robust caching features](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html).

Comment: Gonna take a look into it

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a `RequestContext` solution, as suggested as an answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7323792/rails-share-information-within-a-request-scope) question:

```
class RequestContext

  # ...
  # see answer in link for implementation and scope...
  # ...      

  def the_man
    @the_man ||= Man.find_by(id: 1)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to what @Uri Agassi said but wrapped in a gem: https://github.com/steveklabnik/request_store